# AS3 - Turn classic textfield into TLF textfield

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

I have a **classic** textfield on stage that I would like to turn into a **TLF** textfield. How can this be done?

Thank you. Uli

Comment: You might try to describe your situation, for example in the Flash Professional IDE you can just delete the classic text field and replace it w/a TLF one. Or maybe you want to create the TLF text in AS3? As simple as your question may seem, there are usually more details than just one line of text -- the more effort you show in asking the question, the more likely people are to answer ... and more importantly, the more likely they will be able to help you :)

Comment: Agree with above. How are you creating the TextField and which version of Flash are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If on the stage in Flash Pro, you could simply change the control.

From classic text:

[image: classic-textfield]
[image: classic-textfield-properties]

To TLF text:

[image: tlf-textfield]
[image: tlf-textfield-properties]

Programmatically I don't believe there's typecasting between `flash.text.TextField` and `fl.text.TLFTextField`.

Both share a `.text` property; however, are different in terms of capability such as html and text flow.